# Getting user locale from KeycloakPrincipal

Tags: java, keycloak

I have configured keycloak filter, that sets `KeycloakPrincipal` in `HttpServletRequest`. So far so good.

I've found out where the field `locale` is located:

```
KeycloakPrincipal<KeycloakSecurityContext> principal = (KeycloakPrincipal<KeycloakSecurityContext>) req.getUserPrincipal();
String locale = principal.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken().getLocale();
```

However, I get null, although I see locale in user's profile:

[image: keycloak admin console]

How to get the user locale from the `KeycloakPrincipal`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly add it. In your realm, select the client you use for the user to log in. In mappers, you'll see what's being mapped in the token:

[image]

Here you can add a built-in attribute:

[image]

**See also:**

- [[keycloak-user] retrieving custom user attributes](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2015-October/003221.html)